# Loop Controller for ".each do |x|" in ERB

Tags: ruby, loops, erb

I am trying to style the first element output through an `object.each do |x|` command by applying an .active class. I cannot figure it out though - how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `each_with_index()`. Shown below in a non-ERB example for clarity.

```
['hello', 'world'].each_with_index do |item, index|
  if index == 0
    puts "This is the first item"
  end

  puts item
end
```

Prints out:

```
This is the first item
hello
world
```

Comment: I think this snippet better represents the nature of the task: http://pastie.org/5350910

Answer (score 1):

It seems very obvious:

```
objects.first.css_options += ' .active'
```

And then iterate through all objects in usual manner.

In case of variation can be different, for example you want also apply css option to last element:

```
objects.zip(['active','','',...]).each do |obj,klass|
  obj.css_option += klass
  ...
end
```

Comment: I'm a rails noob so acan you help explain where I would utilize this? is this a helper?  I'm trying to figure out where to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[obj1, obj2].each_with_index do |item, index|
  item.css_option += ' .active' if index == 0
end
```